# set visibility of ApplicationBarIconButton to false in wp7

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

I have an application bar in my windows phone application

```
  <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="Refresh" IconUri="Images/appbar.sync.rest.png" Text="Actualiser" Click="ApplicationBarIconButton_Click" />
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="Favorite"  IconUri="Images/appbar.favs.addto.rest.png" Text="Favorite" Click="ApplicationBarIconButton_Click_1" />
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

I nedd to set the visibility of `<shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="Favorite"  IconUri="Images/appbar.favs.addto.rest.png" Text="Favorite" Click="ApplicationBarIconButton_Click_1" />`
 to false  when i click

How can do this??

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot set visibility of individual buttons in the app bar to collapsed. But you can `enable/disable` them by using the `IsEnabled` property or remove them dynamically from your code behind `ApplicationBar.Buttons.Remove(object)` and pass the button object which you receive on click event. I guess it should work.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is have 2 different AppBars in your application - the first with the 2 `ApplicationBarIconButtons` (Refresh and Favorite) and the second with only the Refresh `ApplicationBarIconButton`.

In your `EventHandler` for `ApplicationBarIconButton_Click_1`, you can change the `AppBar` that is currently being displayed to the user.

Something like this works...

```
ApplicationBar appBar1 = new ApplicationBar();
ApplicationBarIconButton refreshIcon = new ApplicationBarIconButton();
refreshIcon.text = "Refresh";
refreshIcon.Click += new EventHandler(Refresh_Click);
appBar1.add(refreshIcon);

ApplicationBarIconButton favIcon = new ApplicationBarIconButton();
favIcon.text = "Refresh";
favIcon.Click += new EventHandler(Fav_Click);
appBar1.add(favIcon);

ApplicationBar appBar2 = new ApplicationBar();
ApplicationBarIconButton refreshIcon2 = new ApplicationBarIconButton();
refreshIcon2.text = "Refresh";
refreshIcon2.Click += new EventHandler(Refresh_Click);
appBar2.add(refreshIcon2);

ApplicationBar = appBar1; // Assign the AppBar with both buttons as the default.
```

Then in the `EventHandler` for `Fav_Click`, write

```
ApplicationBar = appBar2; // This will make the AppBar with only "Refresh" button visible giving the impression that the Favorite button has been made invisible.
```